# Time to clear border controls when arriving via ferry to Hull

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, borders

I will be soon traveling from Rotterdam to Hull.

What is the average time for disembarking and clearing border controls when arriving via ferry to Hull?

Comment: Between 10 and 90 minutes in my experience (12 trips), but that was all BEFORE Brexit and Covid. I have no idea what it typically is now.

Comment: Are you travelling by car, or on foot? Do you have a British passport? These are surely relevant!

Answer (score 10):

It does depend on whether you are first off or one of the last, but both as foot passenger and as cyclist, so between cars, I have experienced between a few minutes and at most 30 minutes. If you are the last passenger car of a full ferry and there are a few time consuming ones before you, it may take an hour or even longer.

If disembarking time is essential, try talking with boarding staff before you get on so you get a good position to be off fast.

But remember that arrival time is always weather dependant.

Comment: Probably a good idea to arrive at the port in Rotterdam _early_ so you can make sure you're in a good position to depart as quickly as possible.

Comment: With these ferries it is not as easy as first on-first off. So better ask for a good placement.

Comment: I realized as I typed that it might not be clear. Arriving early in Rotterdam allows you time to talk to the boarding staff to ensure you have a good departure position (wherever that may be) and that all the good spots aren't already taken by others in the same rush you are.