# Time to clear border controls when arriving via ferry at Rotterdam

Tags: customs-and-immigration, netherlands, ferries, rotterdam

How long does it take to clear border controls when arriving [by ferry](https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/hull-to-rotterdam-by-ferry.htm) at Rotterdam from Hull?

Comment: What do you mean ? how long it takes to clear the border controls ? or what time the border opens ? or what time the ferry arrives ?

Comment: Previous question [in the other direction](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172410/time-to-clear-border-controls-when-arriving-via-ferry-to-hull).

Answer (score 3):

If you are one of the first of the ferry, a few minutes, if you have to line up at the end of a long queue, half an hour to one hour. Mostly there are not that many foot passengers so that is the shorter time.

In rare circumstances longer is possible.
If you travel by car and need a speedy departure, talk with the boarding staff so you can get a place on the deck that unloads first.

Comment: Any tips on how to be one of the first in the lineup?

Comment: Be early for check-in and ask every staff member you have to see.